# How to merge nested array with main object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Sample Data

```js
const data = [{ id: 1,iitems: [{ id: 1, name: 'R1'}]},{id: 2, items: [{ id: 1, name: 'R2'},{ id: 1, name: 'R3'}]}];

 data.map((item) => item.items).data.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])
 
 console.log(data)
```

What I'm trying to do here is to merge the nested to one array. but the output is like this.

```
data = [
{ id: 1, name: 'R1'},
{ id: 1, name: 'R2'},
{ id: 1, name: 'R3'}]
```

Expected output:

```
 data = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 1, name: 'R1' },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 1, name: 'R2'},
    {id: 1, name: 'R3'}
 ];
```

Comment: Why is `{ "id": 1, "name": "R2"}` not in your expected output?

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to have an array of `items` if you want an array and an array of objects you want references to the original ids?

Comment: @NickParsons already updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can "flatten" your structure like this:

```
let flatten = obj => [obj, ...(obj.items || []).flatMap(flatten)]

let result = data.flatMap(flatten)
```

Note that this performs "deep" flattening, that is, works with sub-objects containing deeper `items` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) where you [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `items` and the rest of the object properties into their own object (`r`). Then you can return an array from the `.flatMap()` to merge all items together into the one resulting array:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1,items: [{ id: 1, name: 'R1'}]},{id: 2, items: [{ id: 1, name: 'R2'},{ id: 1, name: 'R3'}]}];

const res = data.flatMap(({items, ...r}) => [r, ...items]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
const newData = data.map(item => [{id: item.id}, ...item.items]).flat(1)
```

Comment: can i ask why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, you have iitems and items, name error, but here is an aproach:

```
var data = [{ id: 1,items: [{ id: 1, name: 'R1'}]},{id: 2, items: [{ id: 1, name: 'R2'},{ id: 1, name: 'R3'}]}];

var dataNew = [];

data.forEach(element => {
  dataNew.push({
        id: element.id
      })
  if(element.items.length>0){
    element.items.forEach(elementInner => {
      
        dataNew.push({
        id: element.id,
        name:elementInner.name
      })
    })
  }
})

console.log(dataNew)
```

Output:

```
0: Object { id: 1 }
​
1: Object { id: 1, name: "R1" }
​
2: Object { id: 2 }
​
3: Object { id: 2, name: "R2" }
​
4: Object { id: 2, name: "R3" }
​
length: 5
```